# What is the proper word/phrase for SMS style language?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the proper word/phrase for SMS style language? Then one's which are commonly used while sending text messages, containing shortened words, phonetic spelling, multiple punctuations (*?????????????* instead of *?*) etc.

Something like:

> i dun feel the same way about any1 else + i kinda hate galz now , ......i dun want any of em now......my parents want to but i dun .......

I was guessing *improper* but wasn't sure.

Comment: That's generally referred to as *textspeak* (or *txtspk*, if you want to be ironically self-referential).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jargon is the technical term.

There's an exhaustive list on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language) for the subject:

> txt-speak, txtese, chatspeak, txt, txtspk, txtk, txto, texting language, txt lingo, SMSish, txtslang,or txt talk

Some even consider it a unique dialect of the English language.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a pejorative term, "jargon" is a set of terms and phrases with special meanings for a closed group.